# Pass file object directly to nodejs formidable module

Tags: node.js, formidable

I know that form.parse(req, ...) will parse the incoming "form post" request when click "submit" button. If I want simulate "click submit button" by using ajax call with file objects, how shall I do it?

I write it like this but now working

```
$('#uploadFilesInput').change(function() {
        var fileObjs = $(this).val();
        window.alert(fileObjs);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/upload",
            context: fileObjs,
            method: "POST"
            }).done(function() {
                window.alert("test")
            });
    });
```

Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`context: fileObjs,` should be `data: fileObjs` instead. Otherwise it's not sending anything to the server.